# Open source defect tracker which is gamified

Tags: open-source, issue-tracker, gamification

I'm looking for a defect tracker with the following features:

1. Can record email as a defect and generate defect ID.
2. Can have priority, severity defined by projects.
3. Must have gamification features (can add badges, points, caps to boost the testers to improve the quality of testing efforts and increase competitiveness).

Preferably on WAMP or XAMPP stack.