# Open source gamification platform

Tags: android, open-source, gamification

I am trying to learn how to create an Android app where a user community can be built upon gamification.

Users should be able to earn badges, points, ask questions, answer questions.

Is there a simple open source gamification platform that can help me to do that? Preferably Java based for easy integration into the Android app

Comment: Related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/24879/any-recommendations-for-open-source-defect-tracker-which-is-gamified